# Dead Sea Scrolls to purchase for home reading

Tags: discussion

I have been reading up quite a bit the last couple days on the reliability and difference between the Septuagint (LXX) and the Masoretic Text (MT), and have found so much interesting information that I just can't really quite get over it. In any case, I already own the LXX ([Brenton](http://insaner.com/ads/lxx)) and MT ([BHS](http://insaner.com/ads/bhs)) for home reading and study but given what I have recently found, I was wondering if anybody knows where I could potentially purchase (hopefully not too expensive) a copy of (at least) the OT texts found among the Dead Sea Scrolls? I don't mind either way if they are in the Paleo Hebrew script or modern Hebrew script. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Some of the key ones are available online at http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/ (for free). So if you do not mind digital copies, that may be your best bet at examining them.

Answer (score 5):

The site linked by @ScottS is an excellent resource.

If you want a book with Hebrew text, it will cost you. The standard edition is by [Florentino García Martínez and Eibert Tigchelaar](http://www.eerdmans.com/Products/4493/the-dead-sea-scrolls-study-edition-set-of-2-volumes.aspx), although you might find it cheaper somewhere, or [used perhaps](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?isbn=9780802844934&sts=t).

(Only a small number of the scrolls use paleo-Hebrew script, btw.)

Comment: To take a peek inside, I found the amazon link here: http://www.amazon.com/The-Dead-Scrolls-Study-Edition/dp/0802844936#reader_0802844936

Comment: Though I wasn't able to see any actual manuscript text, but it seems that book might be what I am looking for, let me see if I can find a physical copy somewhere.

Comment: @RaphaelRosch - they're not photographs/plates of the actual manuscripts (the websites linked in other answers will give you some of that) -- they are editions of Hebrew (with English, in that edition) much like BHS is to Codex Leningrad. It's a very good edition.

Answer (score 1):

I originally found this one too: [deadseascrolls.org.il](http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive) but it's not really in the format I would like it in (you can see fragments but they aren't lined up to be legible). I'm including it in case it is useful to anyone.